# Setting which configuration to use for riak installed via brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, riak

I just did `brew install --devel riak` to get riak 2.0.1 on my OSX machine. After that I started a node with:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/bin/riak start
```

What I see in `ps ax` is that it's using some `/usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/data/generated.configs/vm.2014.10.03.11.27.37.args` config:

```
➜  ~  ps ax | grep riak
96269   ??  S      0:00.01 /usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/erts-5.10.3/bin/epmd -daemon
96277   ??  S      0:00.00 /usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/erts-5.10.3/bin/run_erl -daemon /tmp/riak// /usr/local/var/log/riak exec /usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/bin/riak console
96849 s013  R+     0:00.00 grep riak
96279 s017  Rs+    8:59.91 /usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/erts-5.10.3/bin/beam.smp -P 256000 -e 256000 -Q 65536 -A 64 -K true -W w -zdbbl 32768 -- -root /usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec -progname riak -- -home /Users/kb -- -boot /usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/releases/2.0.1/riak -config /usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/data/generated.configs/app.2014.10.03.11.27.37.config -setcookie riak -name riak@127.0.0.1 -smp enable -vm_args /usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/data/generated.configs/vm.2014.10.03.11.27.37.args -pa /usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/lib/basho-patches -- console
```

As I understand, what I'd like to have is to use `/usr/local/Cellar/riak/2.0.1/libexec/etc/riak.conf` config, which is much more like good old `/etc/riak.conf` from linux.

What should I do to use it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key word there is `generated`. The script that starts Riak takes the `riak.conf` file. It converts that from the dotted format that is nice for people to edit, to the app.config and vm.args format that erlang wants to read.  It then merges it with any advanced.config file that may be there, and writes it to `generated.configs`, and has erlang use that.  Even on linux, it doesn't use riak.conf directly, but rather a generated config based on it.

If you want the why and how, take a look at the [cuttlefish repo](https://github.com/basho/cuttlefish)

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed this and wanted to go here and write an answer :)